# TightVNC No route to host

Tags: networking, routing, tightvnc

I am getting this error when I try to connect to my remote PC.
Which is a windows Vista machine running TightVNC server on port 5900.

Here are some outputs:

```
ping 84.163.12.3
PING 84.163.12.3 (84.163.12.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 84.163.12.3: icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=57.4 ms
64 bytes from 84.163.12.3: icmp_req=2 ttl=59 time=57.5 ms
64 bytes from 84.163.12.3: icmp_req=3 ttl=59 time=57.2 ms


traceroute 84.163.12.3
traceroute to 84.163.12.3 (84.163.12.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  speedport.ip (192.168.2.1)  0.556 ms  0.762 ms  9.168 ms
 2  217.0.119.23 (217.0.119.23)  25.791 ms  26.361 ms  26.373 ms
 3  87.186.254.54 (87.186.254.54)  31.085 ms  31.076 ms  31.057 ms
 4  ka-eb1-i.KA.DE.NET.DTAG.DE (62.154.74.170)  29.643 ms  29.697 ms  29.680 ms
 5  217.0.68.49 (217.0.68.49)  28.549 ms  29.641 ms  30.026 ms
 6  p54A30C03.dip0.t-ipconnect.de (84.163.12.3)  67.047 ms !X  57.470 ms !X  58.563 ms !X


iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    


netstat -nr
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

From the last traceroute result !X I think means timeout?
That makes me think it could be a firewall, but I have added an exception to the windows firewall during installation. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a router in between the vista machine and it's internet connection?  You will need to NAT port 5900 from the outside to the address of the vista machine.  Because of these kinds of challenges, many use GoToMyPC or Teamviewer or another remote access software because they send their information over ports that are generally allowed by the router.

Comment: Of course that must be it! Thanks for your tips!